# Can you center labels inside map fields (states, counties, etc.)?

Tags: label, tableau-api

When I choose "Middle" alignment for the labels for geographic fields, the labels don't really move.

Are labels "centered" already for geographic fields by default?

When I show labels for county fields and choose middle alignment, the labels don't move.

[Screenshot from sample Superstore Data. Default label alignment is the same as middle alignment. Default label alignment also looks centered for states. It is harder to tell if labels are centered for smaller shapes such as counties.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuAed.png)

Answer (score 0):

yes the labels are centered by default for geographic fields. I agree that it is hard to tell for smaller shapes as well as for large countries that have a unique shape.